# How to save data to mysql database using vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

hEy help me to find error at this code :)
I'm new to vb.net friends

```
Try
        /*'con.Open()*/
        Query = "INSERT INTO mcs.custormer VALUES(custormer_id,first_name,last_name,nic_no,c_address1,c_address2,c_address3,c_telephoneno,membership_date,business_name,g_name,g_nicno,g_address1,g_address2,g_address3,g_telephoneNO)" & _
            "VALUES (@custormer_id,@first_name,@last_name,@nic_no,@c_address1,@c_address2,@c_address3,@c_telephoneNO,@membership_date,@business_name,@g_name,@g_nicno,@g_address1,@g_address2,@g_address3,@g_telephoneNO)"
        Using cmd = New MySqlCommand(Query, con)

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custormer_id", Convert.ToInt32(txtcustormerid.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", Convert.ToString(txtfirstname.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", Convert.ToString(txtlastname.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nic_no", Convert.ToString(txtnicno.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_address1", Convert.ToString(txtcaddress1.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_address2", Convert.ToString(txtcaddress2.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_address3", Convert.ToString(txtcaddress3.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_telephoneNO", Convert.ToString(txtctelephoneno.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@membership_date", Convert.ToDateTime(dtpmembrshipdate.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@business_name", Convert.ToString(txtbusinessname.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g_name", Convert.ToString(txtgname.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g_nicno", Convert.ToString(txtgnicno.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g_address1", Convert.ToString(txtgaddress1.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g_address2", Convert.ToString(txtgaddress2.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g_address3", Convert.ToString(txtgaddress3.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g_telephoneNO", Convert.ToString(txtgtelephoneno.Text))
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("New Custormer Added Sucsessfully !")
            txtcustormerid.Clear()
            txtfirstname.Clear()
            txtlastname.Clear()
            txtnicno.Clear()
            txtcaddress1.Clear()
            txtcaddress2.Clear()
            txtcaddress3.Clear()
            txtctelephoneno.Clear()
            txtbusinessname.Clear()
            txtgname.Clear()
            txtgaddress1.Clear()
            txtgaddress2.Clear()
            txtgaddress3.Clear()
            txtgtelephoneno.Clear()
            txtgnicno.Clear()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        'da.Dispose()
        'ds.Clear()
        ' dr.Close()
        cmd.Dispose()
        con.Close()
    End Try
```

When I click save button it get this error,

[image]

I try more and more, but I can't go forward. Please help me guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with

```
 Query = "INSERT INTO mcs.custormer (custormer_id,first_name,last_name,nic_no,c_address1,c_address2,c_address3,c_telephoneno,membership_date,business_name,g_name,g_nicno,g_address1,g_address2,g_address3,g_telephoneNO)" & _
            "VALUES (@custormer_id,@first_name,@last_name,@nic_no,@c_address1,@c_address2,@c_address3,@c_telephoneNO,@membership_date,@business_name,@g_name,@g_nicno,@g_address1,@g_address2,@g_address3,@g_telephoneNO)"
```

also please refer [Mysql Insert Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html).hope this helps.

Comment: ah it's really helped! resolved my problem :) Thank you bro :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  INSERT INTO mcs.custormer
        (  /*no need to use VALUES keyword, here you are 
            specifying the column list in which data need to be  
            inserted*/ 
        custormer_id
        ,first_name
        ,last_name
        ,nic_no
        ,c_address1
        ,c_address2
        ,c_address3
        ,c_telephoneno
        ,membership_date
        ,business_name
        ,g_name
        ,g_nicno
        ,g_address1
        ,g_address2
        ,g_address3
        ,g_telephoneNO
        ) 
    VALUES ( /* use VALUES keyword, because in this clause you're  
                passing values for each columns*/
        @custormer_id
        ,@first_name
        ,@last_name
        ,@nic_no
        ,@c_address1
        ,@c_address2
        ,@c_address3
        ,@c_telephoneNO
        ,@membership_date
        ,@business_name
        ,@g_name
        ,@g_nicno
        ,@g_address1
        ,@g_address2
        ,@g_address3
        ,@g_telephoneNO
        )
```

---

Possible SQL Insert statements are

The first form does not specify the column names where the data will be inserted, only their values:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

and

The second form specifies both the column names and the values to be inserted:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

Comment: yeh it improved my sql language :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "VALUES" from this part of your code.

```
INSERT INTO mcs.custormer VALUES...
```

The correct syntax should be:

```
INSERT INTO table_Name (Field1,Field2) VALUES (Value1, Value2)
```